# Fetch Shared Outlook Calendar Events C#

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, office-interop

I know how to retrieve events in the current user's outlook calendar, the following code works to remove items matching a certain pattern for instance:

```
private void RemoveAppointments()
        {
            Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MAPIFolder calendarFolder = outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = calendarFolder.Items;
            for (int i = outlookCalendarItems.Count; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (outlookCalendarItems[i].Subject.Contains("On Call: Regions:") && outlookCalendarItems[i].Start.Year == _year)
                {
                    outlookCalendarItems[i].Delete();
                }
            }
        }
```

However, I now need to be able to read calendar events from all users within an Outlook Team (assume sharing permissions have been set correctly). Ideally I need to be able to iterate per user but if I just get a collection of all events and can then query that by user that would suffice too.

Any ideas where I can start?

---

Note: this is how the team is represented withing the Calendar pane of Outlook. Sensitive details redacted.

[image: Calendar Section Bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Dmitry for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51920498/4700841) which helped me solve my issue. However, to maximise the utility of this question for future readers I thought I'd expand on it.

---

Assume that:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

and that the COM assembly `Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library` is referenced.

---

The first step is to create an `Outlook.Application` object that serves as an interface to Outlook's functions (you can think of it as an internal instance of the full Outlook program):

```
Application app = new Application();
```

From this I then pull all of the users from the distribution list in the Global Address List that is associated with the team. This is done by creating a `Recipient` object from the `Session` property of the `Application` instance.

```
Recipient distList = app.Session.CreateRecipient(yourDistList);
```

From here we can pull all of the real names and usernames vie the `AdressEntry.Members` property of our Recipient. To pull these both into an anonymous tuple of `(string,string)` we can use this LINQ query, if you don't like that you can just iterate like normal:

```
List<(string,string)> usersData = distList.AddressEntry.Members.Cast<AddressEntry>().Select(entry => (entry.Name,entry.Address)).ToList();
```

Now, given a specific username, as long as the calendar has been shared with the curernt user you can access it using the `GetSharedDefaultFolder()` method of the `Session`:

```
MAPIFolder sharedCalendar = _app.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(teamMember, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
```

At this point I found it useful to do some filtering to try and avoid the most common `COMException`s however, there are plenty I can't seem to determine the cause of so I just `catch (COMException)` and bin them off. Not good practice I know but it didn't seem to interfere with me accessing calendars that I had permissions for. Some (very) basic filtering:

```
if (sharedCalendar.DefaultMessageClass != "IPM.Appointment" || teamMember.DisplayType != 0)
{
    return null; //Calendar not shared.
}
```

Now we have to build a `Filter` string utilising the Microsoft Outlook format, this can be done using the following statement (where `from` and `to` are both `DateTime` objects):

```
string sFilter = $"[End] > '{from:g}' AND [Start] < '{to:g}' AND [Recurring] = 'No'";
```

We filter out recurring events as otherwise the Start and End dates can be wildly outside the range with no internal occurrences. For my purposes, I didn't need recurring events anyway, however, if you do you will have to deal with this separately.

Finally we can now collect the events we need utilising the `Items.Restrict()` method of `MAPIFolder`:

```
Items results = sharedCalendar.Items.Restrict(sFilter);
```

This returns an `Items` interface to all of the items falling within our filter.

Finally, we can iterate over each item (I iterate in reverse order because I copied code from an old application of mine that deleted events but it shouldn't matter in this context). You may have to cast the `object` to `AppointmentItem` depending on whether or not this can be inferred by the compiler.

```
List<AppData> appointments = new List<AppData>();
for (int i = results.Count; i > 0; i--)
{
    appointments.Add(new AppData(results[i], username));
}
```

I store each event as an `AppData` struct keeping only the data I need:

```
public struct AppData
{
    public string Subject { get; }
    public DateTime From { get; }      
    public DateTime To { get; }       
    public string Location { get; }      
    public string Categories { get; }      
    public string Username { get; }
    public AppData(AppointmentItem appItem, string username)
    {
        Subject = appItem.Subject;
        From = appItem.Start;
        To = appItem.End;
        Location = appItem.Location;
        Categories = appItem.Categories;
        Username = username;
    }
}
```

---

All of this results in a class that looks as such:

```
public class OutlookCommunicator : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Application _app;

    public OutlookCommunicator()
    {
        _app = new Application();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Username of the distribution list according to the GAL.
    /// </summary>
    private const string DistList = "redacted";

    /// <summary>
    /// Fetches a list of all usernames and names within the DistList.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>List&lt;string&gt; containing all usernames.</returns>
    public List<(string,string)> GetUsers()
    {
            Recipient warEngineering = _app.Session.CreateRecipient(DistList);
            List<(string,string)> usernames = warEngineering.AddressEntry.Members.Cast<AddressEntry>().Select(entry => (entry.Name,entry.Address)).ToList();
            return usernames;

    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Fetches all calendar events for a user falling within the provided range.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="from">Start search date.</param>
    /// <param name="to">End search dat.</param>
    /// <param name="username">User's calendar to search.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<AppData> GetEventsInRange(DateTime from, DateTime to, string username)
    {
        List<AppData> appointments = new List<AppData>();
        try
        {

            Recipient teamMember = _app.Session.CreateRecipient(username);
            MAPIFolder sharedCalendar = _app.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(teamMember, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            if (sharedCalendar.DefaultMessageClass != "IPM.Appointment" || teamMember.DisplayType != 0)
            {
                return null; //Calendar not shared.
            }

            string sFilter = $"[End] > '{from:g}' AND [Start] < '{to:g}' AND [Recurring] = 'No'";
            Items results = sharedCalendar.Items.Restrict(sFilter);
            for (int i = results.Count; i > 0; i--)
            {
                appointments.Add(new AppData(results[i], username));
            }

            return appointments;
        }
        catch (COMException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _app?.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution with detailed explanation - this definitely helps.I would like to know how access to outlook is so for example if I have a web application accessing outloook calendars ..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`, use `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder`, passing a `Recipient` object returned from `Namespace.CreateRecipient`.

Also keep in mind that looping through *all* items in a folder is a horrible idea, especially if you open an online folder not cached in a local OST file. Use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` instead.

Comment: That's a useful start but it still requires me to have the recipient name, is there any way to pull this information from a team?

Comment: Sure, that team is represented as a GAL entry, right? Find it in the address book (CreateRecipient / Recipeint.Resolve is one one), then loop through the entries in the AddressEntry.Members collection.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I'll add  some code to your answer when I've got it done.

Comment: On the advice of meta, I've posted my additions as my own answer, thank you for your help though!

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko  
I will see if I can apply this to my similar issue, only I'll be using your Redemption product.